# The definition of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ is that if, for every $M>0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if, $n\ge N$, then $a_n>M$. But I would like to change it so that I can get the definition for $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$. This is what I get:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$ if for every $M<0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\ge N$, then $a_n <M$.

Is this the correct way to describe $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$ ?

I'm also wondering how to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n\neq -\infty$, if $r<-1$. Any suggestion of idea of proof or how to approach it would greatly help.

Thank you!

Comment: For the second question, $r^{2n}>0$ is enough ! (Because the limit of this subsequence cannot be negative.)

Comment: For the definition, I don't think that $M>0$ is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: YES, what you have written is corect.

Second question: Just apply the definition you just gave and note that there are even integers $\geq N$. If $n$ one such integer then we get $0 \leq r^{n} <M$ which cannot be true when $M <0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have in fact used the obvious transformation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}-a_n=\infty.$$

---

You also changed the sign of $M$, but that sign is irrelevant.